# How to send the ouput of show command to custom library of Robot framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I am planning to automate the following scenario:

```
STEP 1 : Launch gmail page in firefox browser
STEP 2 : Enter username and password
STEP 3 : Press signin button
STEP 4 : When above 3 steps are happening, my router will recognize as gmail traffic and show in "show dpi app stats gmail on AVC/test-15E8CC" command output.
STEP 5 : Custom library should check the output of above show command and decide whether test is FAIL or PASS
```

For the above purpose I have written "pass_fail.robot" as shown below:

```
*** Settings ***
Library         Selenium2Library
Library         SSHLibrary
Library         regexp_def.py
Suite Setup     Go to gmail page
Suite Teardown  Close All Browsers

*** Variables ***
${HOMEPAGE}     https://www.gmail.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html
${BROWSER}      firefox
${LOGINPAGE}    https://www.gmail.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html
${FINALURL}     https://mail.google.com/mail/
${FINALURL1}    https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/'

${HOST}             1.1.1.1
${USERNAME}         test
${PASSWORD}         test

*** Test Cases ***
Login into gmail
    Go to gmail page
Login Page Should Be Open
    Click Signin Button
Input Username      test@gmail.com
Input Password      test@123
Submit Credentials
Inbox page should open

Check Deep Packet Inspection Stats
    Open Connection         ${HOST}
    enable ssh logging      XYZ
    Login   ${USERNAME}     ${PASSWORD}
    Write                   enable
    Write                   show dpi app stats gmail on AVC/switch-15E8CC
    ${x}                    Read Until Regexp       .*#

Check Pass Fail Criteria
    pass fail criteria



*** Keywords ***
Go to gmail page
    Open Browser    ${HOMEPAGE}     ${BROWSER}
    Maximize Browser Window

Login Page Should Be Open
    Location Should Be      ${LOGINPAGE}    

Click Signin Button
    Click Element       id=gmail-sign-in

Input Username
    [Arguments]     ${username}
    Input Text      id=Email    ${username}


Input Password
    [Arguments]     ${password}
    Input Text      id=Passwd   ${password}

Submit Credentials
    Click Button    id=signIn

Inbox page should open
    Location Should Be      ${FINALURL}
```

My custom Library "regexp_def.py" is looks like this:

```
import re

'''

#Following is the sample content of x variable should get from robot framework:


x="""router-7F2C13#show app stats gmail on TEST/switch1234-15E8CC
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     APPLICATION           BYTES_IN         BYTES_OUT           NUM_FLOWS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  gmail                0                 0                  0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
router-7F2C13#
---------------------------------------------------------------
router-7F2C13#"""
'''


def pass_fail_criteria():
    if int(re.findall(r"NUM_FLOWS\n-+[\s\S]*?(\d+)\s*-+",x)[0]):
        print "pass"
    else:
        print "fail"

pass_fail_criteria()
```

When I run this test I am getting following error:

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria>pybot pass_
fail.robot
    [ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_
fail_criteria\pass_fail.robot': Importing test library 'C:\Users\test\Desktop\
Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria\regexp_def.py' failed: NameError: g
lobal name 'x' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria\reg
    exp_def.py", line 26, in <module>
pass_fail_criteria()
  File "C:\Users\test\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria\reg
exp_def.py", line 21, in pass_fail_criteria
    if int(re.findall(r"NUM_FLOWS\n-+[\s\S]*?(\d+)\s*-+",x)[0]):
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robot\libraries
  c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pycrypto-2.6-py2.7-win32.egg
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
  C:\Python27\Lib
  C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
  C:\Python27\DLLs
  C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
  C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
  C:\Python27
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
  .
    ==============================================================================
Pass Fail
    ==============================================================================
Login into gmail                                                      | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Check Deep Packet Inspection Stats                                    | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Check Pass Fail Criteria                                              | FAIL |
No keyword with name 'pass fail criteria' found.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pass Fail                                                             | FAIL |
3 critical tests, 2 passed, 1 failed
3 tests total, 2 passed, 1 failed
 ==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Users\test\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria\ou
tput.xml
Log:     C:\Users\test\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria\lo
g.html
Report:  C:\Users\test\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria\re
port.html

 C:\Users\test\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria>
```

Could any one please look into this.

I am seeing problem in sending required data (output of show command to "${x}") to the custom library .

Is there any other issue. Please guide me on this.

## New files modified as per "Bryan Oakley" comments:

regexp_def.py file contents:

```
import re

def pass_fail_criteria():
    if int(re.findall(r"NUM_FLOWS\n-+[\s\S]*?(\d+)\s*-+",x)[0]):
        return "pass"
    else:
        return "fail"
```

pass_fail.robot file contents:

```
*** Settings ***
Library         Selenium2Library
Library         SSHLibrary
Library         regexp_def.py
Suite Setup     Go to gmail page
Suite Teardown  Close All Browsers

*** Variables ***
${HOMEPAGE}     https://www.gmail.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html
${BROWSER}      firefox
${LOGINPAGE}    https://www.gmail.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html
${FINALURL}     https://mail.google.com/mail/
${FINALURL1}    https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/'

${HOST}             10.1.1.2
${USERNAME}         admin
${PASSWORD}         moto

*** Test Cases ***
Login into gmail
    Go to gmail page
    Login Page Should Be Open
    Click Signin Button
    Input Username      zebradtc@gmail.com
    Input Password      Zebra@123
    Submit Credentials
    Inbox page should open

Check Deep Packet Inspection Stats
    Open Connection         ${HOST}
    enable ssh logging      XYZ
    Login   ${USERNAME}     ${PASSWORD}
    Write                   enable
    Write                   show dpi app stats gmail on AVC/ap7532-15E8CC
    ${x}                    Read Until Regexp       .*#

Check Pass Fail Criteria
    ${result}   pass fail criteria      ${x}        




*** Keywords ***
Go to gmail page
    Open Browser    ${HOMEPAGE}     ${BROWSER}
    Maximize Browser Window

Login Page Should Be Open
    Location Should Be      ${LOGINPAGE}    

Click Signin Button
    Click Element       id=gmail-sign-in

Input Username
    [Arguments]     ${username}
    Input Text      id=Email    ${username}

Input Password
    [Arguments]     ${password}
    Input Text      id=Passwd   ${password}

Submit Credentials
    Click Button    id=signIn

Inbox page should open
    Location Should Be      ${FINALURL}


#${status}          pass fail criteria
should be equal    ${status}             pass


# pass ${x} to the custom keyword
${result}          Pass fail criteria      ${x}
```

After modifying these files I am getting following error:

```
C:\Users\symbol\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria>pybot pass_
fail.robot
==============================================================================
Pass Fail
==============================================================================
Login into gmail                                                      | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
Keyword '${result}' expected 0 arguments, got 2.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Check Deep Packet Inspection Stats                                    | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
Keyword '${result}' expected 0 arguments, got 2.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Check Pass Fail Criteria                                              | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
Keyword '${result}' expected 0 arguments, got 2.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pass Fail                                                             | FAIL |
Suite setup failed:
Keyword '${result}' expected 0 arguments, got 2.

Also suite teardown failed:
Variable '${x}' not found.

3 critical tests, 0 passed, 3 failed
3 tests total, 0 passed, 3 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Users\symbol\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria\ou
tput.xml
Log:     C:\Users\symbol\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria\lo
g.html
Report:  C:\Users\symbol\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria\re
port.html

C:\Users\symbol\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have several problems going on. We'll tackle them one at a time.

### Don't call the function when you import the library

Libraries are used for defining keywords, not calling them. 
You are calling `pass_fail_critiera` at the time you import the library, when you only want to call it once a test is running.

The fix for that is to remove `pass_fail_criteria()` from the end of your library file, so that the file contains the `def`, but does not directly call the function.

This is why you get the stack trace before you even try to use the keyword in a test case -- the error is happening at import time because the function is being called when the file is imported.

### Keyword should return a result or raise an exception

Your `pass_fail_criteria` keyword needs to either return "pass" or "fail", or it should return silently on success and throw an exception on error. Which you choose is somewhat a matter of preference. Do you want the keyword to always succeed so you can test the result later, or do you want it to fail if your criterial fails?

Here is an example if you want it to always succeed:

```
def pass_fail_criteria():
    if int(...):
        return "pass"
    else:
        return "fail"
```

You would then use the keyword like this in a test case or keyword:

```
${status}          pass fail criteria
should be equal    ${status}             pass
```

### Accessing variable ${x}

The third problem is that even if you do call `pass_fail_criteria` from a test script, it can't access the robot variable `x`. You need to pass that in when you call the keyword, or you need to fetch it via the built-in keyword [Get Variable Value](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Variable%20Value). There is an example of how to do call built-in keywords in the user guide (see the section titled [Using Robot Framework's internal modules](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-robot-framework-s-internal-modules)).

To accept `x` as a keyword argument you will need to modify your function like so:

```
def pass_fail_criteria(x):
    if int(re.findall(r"NUM_FLOWS\n-+[\s\S]*?(\d+)\s*-+",x)[0]):
        return "pass"
    else:
        return "fail"
```

To pass the value in, you do it like any other keyword. You don't show how you are calling the keyword, but it should look something like this:

Check Deep Packet Inspection Stats
    ...
    # set the value ${x}
    ${x}                    Read Until Regexp       .*#

```
# pass ${x} to the custom keyword
${result}               Pass fail criteria      ${x}
```

With the above, the robot variable `${x}` will become the python variable `x` within the function `pass_fail_criteria`

### Creating a keyword called ${result}

After reading my original answer, you amended your question to report a new error, which is `Keyword '${result}' expected 0 arguments, got 2.`.

This is because you are creating a keyword named `${result}` in these lines of code:

```
*** Keywords ***
...
# pass ${x} to the custom keyword
${result}          Pass fail criteria      ${x}
```

I do not know what you are attempting to do there, but whatever it is, it's the wrong thing to do. You shouldn't create a keyword that has the same name as a variable. You need to remove those lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am getting following errors now: Parent suite setup failed:
Keyword '${result}' expected 0 arguments, got 2.  AND Also suite teardown failed:
Variable '${x}' not found.     I have given the my current modified files in my question, Under section : "New files modified as per "Bryan Oakley" comments:". Please suggest me your ideas to fix this issue.

Comment: @balu: stackoverflow isn't a discussion forum. If you have additional questions, please ask them separately. There is no way to properly answer in a tiny comment box. That being said, the only way to get the error you say you do is if you create a keyword named `${status}, which you definitely should not do.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I tried your steps 1 and 2. Its resolved my first exception issue. But still I am seeing error "NameError: global name 'x' is not defined" error. I will try this, If its not working will ask that in separate question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am unable to fix the variable ${x} issue. As you said I have asked this in new question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28209003/how-to-resolve-nameerror-global-name-x-is-not-defined-error-while-running-r". Could you please suggest me fix for this? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

lobal name 'x' is not defined

```
def pass_fail_criteria():
    if int(re.findall(r"NUM_FLOWS\n-+[\s\S]*?(\d+)\s*-+",x)[0]):
        print "pass"
    else:
        print "fail"
```

You forgot x in your parameter list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please tell me how to give "$x" in parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not available for the custom library automatically (you define X, but you don't pass it to the library.

You can either pass X to the pass fail keyword (as an input) - recommanded.

Or you can do it the silly way by importing the builtin robot library and extracting the value of X that way (not recommanded)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sorry. I am new to RFW. Could you please little elaborate on this.  Should I give "pass fail criteria      ${x} " as keyword?