# How can I resolve "NameError: global name 'x' is not defined" error while running a Robot Framework testcase using a custom library?

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework

I am seeing the "NameError: global name 'x' is not defined" error while running a testcase in Robot Framework.

Following is my custom library file (modified as per Bryan Oakley's comments):

```python
import re

def pass_fail_criteria():
    if int(re.findall(r"NUM_FLOWS\n-+[\s\S]*?(\d+)\s*-+", x)[0]):
        return "pass"
    else:
        return "fail"
```

Following is the "pass_fail.robot" file contents:

```
*** Settings ***
Library         Selenium2Library
Library         SSHLibrary
Library         regexp_def.py
Suite Setup     Go to gmail page
Suite Teardown  Close All Browsers

*** Variables ***
${HOMEPAGE}     https://www.gmail.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html
${BROWSER}      firefox
${LOGINPAGE}    https://www.gmail.com/intl/en/mail/help/about.html
${FINALURL}     https://mail.google.com/mail/
${FINALURL1}    https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/'

${HOST}         1.1.1.1
${USERNAME}     test
${PASSWORD}     test



*** Test Cases ***
Login into gmail
    Go to gmail page
    Login Page Should Be Open
    Click Signin Button
    Input Username        test@gmail.com
    Input Password        test@123
    Submit Credentials
    Inbox page should open

Check Deep Packet Inspection Stats
    Open Connection         ${HOST}
    enable ssh logging      XYZ
    Login    ${USERNAME}    ${PASSWORD}
    Write                   enable
    Write                   show dpi app stats gmail on AVC/ap7532-15E8CC
    ${x}                    Read Until Regexp   .*#


Pass fail Criteria
    ${status}               pass fail criteria
    should be equal         ${status}           pass
    ${result}               Pass fail criteria  ${x}

*** Keywords ***
Go to gmail page
    Open Browser    ${HOMEPAGE}     ${BROWSER}
    Maximize Browser Window

Login Page Should Be Open
    Location Should Be        ${LOGINPAGE}

Click Signin Button
    Click Element     id=gmail-sign-in

Input Username
    [Arguments]       ${username}
    Input Text        id=Email    ${username}


Input Password
    [Arguments]       ${password}
    Input Text        id=Passwd    ${password}

Submit Credentials
    Click Button    id=signIn

Inbox page should open
    Location Should Be        ${FINALURL}
```

I am getting the following error while running this file:

```
C:\Users\symbol\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria>pybot pass_
fail.robot
==============================================================================
Pass Fail
==============================================================================
Login into gmail                                                      | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Check Deep Packet Inspection Stats                                    | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pass fail Criteria                                                    | FAIL |
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pass Fail                                                             | FAIL |
3 critical tests, 2 passed, 1 failed
3 tests total, 2 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Users\symbol\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria\ou
tput.xml
Log:     C:\Users\symbol\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria\lo
g.html
Report:  C:\Users\symbol\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria\re
port.html

C:\Users\symbol\Desktop\Projects\gmail_stats_with_pass_fail_criteria>
```

There are issues in the below code:

```
Pass fail Criteria
    ${status}           pass fail criteria
    should be equal     ${status}             pass
    ${result}           Pass fail criteria    ${x}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `x` is not define in code

Comment: You're testing your regular expression on the variable `x`, which you haven't defined anywhere. Perhaps you need to pass it as an argument to `pass_fail_criteria(x)`?

Comment: @Evert Thanks for your comments. I am not getting an idea on how to pass this as argument to my testcase. Could you please tell me, how to pass this ${x} as argument for Robot framework testcase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems working against you. It seems like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how Python-based keywords work.

### Two keywords with the same name

You are defining and importing a library named regexp_def.py. In it there is one keyword, "pass_fail_criteria". Robot will remove the underscores, so from Robot's perspective, this keyword is named "Pass fail criteria".

In your test case you are also creating a keyword called "Pass fail criteria". It is unclear why you're doing that. Do not do that. Remove that keyword; it is unnecessary.

### The variables "x" and "${x}"

You are using a variable `x` in `pass_fail_criteria`, but you haven't defined it. That is what the error is telling you. You need to define it, or pass it in. To pass it in you need to make it a parameter, and then you need to provide a value for that parameter. This is no different than any other keyword, or any other function.

In file *regexp_def.py*:

```
import re

def pass_fail_criteria(x):
    if int(re.findall(r"NUM_FLOWS\n-+[\s\S]*?(\d+)\s*-+",x)[0]):
        return "pass"
    else:
        return "fail"
```

(notice the added parameter in the definition)

In your test case:

```
Pass fail Criteria
    ${status}               pass fail criteria    ${x}
```

(notice the argument on the end of the second line)

### Independent test cases

The way you currently have your test cases structured, you are defining `${x}` in one test case, and then attempting to use it in another. I don't know if this was intentional or not, but many people consider this bad test case design. Test cases should be as independent as possible.

While you *can* do this (using the built-in keyword [Set Suite Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable)), I recommend calling `pass fail criteria` in the test case named "Check Deep Packet Inspection Stats", where `${x}` is defined.

For example:

```
Check Deep Packet Inspection Stats
    ...
    ${x}                    Read Until Regexp       .*#
    ${status}               pass fail criteria      ${x}
    Run keyword if          "${status}" == "pass"   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I am getting "Variable '${x}' not found." error as shown above. (Added my modified Testcase in your answer itself). Please look into this.

Comment: Then I tried by declaring "${x}" in variable section, I am getting "IndexError: index out of range: 0". I am seeing ${x} contains the required output in my previous Testcase.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is not defined and you are using `x` in the following statement.

`if int(re.findall(r"NUM_FLOWS\n-+[\s\S]*?(\d+)\s*-+",x)[0]):`

Pass `x` as an argument to function `pass_fail_criteria(x)` and use `try except`

```
def pass_fail_criteria(x):
    try:
        a = int(re.findall(r"NUM_FLOWS\n-+[\s\S]*?(\d+)\s*-+",x)[0])
        return "pass"
    except:
        return "fail"
```

Comment: Why `try` `except`, and in particular, why  catch-all `except`?

Comment: @Evert: because when result of `re` is empty list then this will raise `IndexError` exception to get `[0]` item from result, so use try except.

Comment: @Vivek Sable  Now I am getting "Keyword 'regexp_def.Pass Fail Criteria' expected 1 argument, got 0." error when I use the try...except code that you mentioned above.

Comment: @balu How you are calling this `pass_fail_criteria(x)` function? and what is value of `x`?

Comment: @Vivek Sable  The value of "X" is the output of cisco show command from the previous setup in robot framework testcase. I am calling this as shown below:   Pass fail Criteria 
 ${status}            pass fail criteria
 should be equal      ${status}             pass
 ${result}               Pass fail criteria

Comment: I know only python part. This exception comes when function call without argument..